# Jar архив не запускается если находится в папке с кирилическими символами

Tags: windows, пакет, символы, jar, java

Создаю jar архив, пробую запустить его в корне диска C: - все работает, если же создаю папку с любым именем содержащим кириллические символы (например "C:проект") файл не запускается, в любой папке с латиницей работает отлично, по сей же причине не запускается на рабочем столе:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Рабочий стол\java\
```

есть ли способ заставить архив работать, если в пути к нему есть кириллические символы?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Задайте в командной строке:

```
dir * /x
```

он выдаст что-то типа:

> 02.03.2012  15:17    <DIR>          0016~1       Рабочий стол

Четвертая колонка это есть сокращенное наименование в формате 8.3 без кириллических символов и пробелов (в данном случае **0016~1**). Вставляйте полученное короткое имя и все заработает.

Comment: я имел в виду что не работает запуск архива двойным кликом, эту кодировку нельзя прописать куданибудь в манифест, или чтото в этом роде?

Comment: нет, нельзя сделайте батник (BAT файл) где и пропишите: java -jar <filename>

Comment: > нет, нельзя сделайте батник (BAT файл) где и пропишите: java -jar <filename>

нельзя, но можно: батник положить в папку `system`, поменять команду в реестре для запуска `.jar` файлов ч/з батник. возможно придется врапнуть первый параметр в скобки (путь к jar-файлу) и сдвинуть остальные (если есть необходимость)